# Hibernate - mapping three tables with annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I have three tables: User, Role, Board. Each user can have many boards, but in one board user can have only one role. I created three classes and I added annotations:

```
class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "mail")
   private String mail;
   ...

   @JoinTable(name = "userBoardRole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", unique = false))
   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "board_id", unique = false)
   @ElementCollection
   private Map<Board, Role> boardRoleMap = new HashMap<Board, Role>();
}

class Role {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "role_id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
   ...
}

class Board {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "role_id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
   ...
}
```

Hibernate create a new table, which look like this:

> CREATE TABLE `userboardrole` (
>     `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>     `role_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>     `board_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`board_id`),
>     **UNIQUE KEY `UK_3lunj2moakkbpehqwqkjcvlf4` (`role_id`),**
>     KEY `FK_3lunj2moakkbpehqwqkjcvlf4` (`role_id`),
>     KEY `FK_ta3fwgh4sln85f6f3jjbte38u` (`board_id`),
>     KEY `FK_lgd2b2mph9qoc1pe2h9r2wu8u` (`id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `FK_lgd2b2mph9qoc1pe2h9r2wu8u` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `FK_3lunj2moakkbpehqwqkjcvlf4` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `boardrole` (`role_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `FK_ta3fwgh4sln85f6f3jjbte38u` FOREIGN KEY (`board_id`) REFERENCES `boards` (`board_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

The problem is that the column role_id is unique. Is there any way, using annotations, to set column unique to false? Thank you for any help.

I'm using hibernate 4.2.2.

Comment: I think adding @ManyToMany annotation to your map will remove the unique role_id constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint, not sure if this solves it: why don't you use `@ManyToMany` annotation and use `@ElementCollection` instead? `@ElementCollection` is usually associated with a `@CollectionTable` and not with a `@JoinTable`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I removed `@ElementCollection` and I added `@ManyToMany` and the table look likes good. Thank you!